# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 - Narrative repeats referenced value

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, oracle12c, obiee

I am facing problems with narratives in the latest OBIEE release (12.1.2.2).

For some reason narratives are displaying the referenced values more then once. Additionally other referenced values are ignored (i.e. 15,16,17,...). (There are no restrictions, filters, ...).

See picture:
[image: picture]

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) 12.2.1.2
b) Narratives display data precisely at the grain of your query. So if you have other columns in your criteria which force the grain to a lower level and hence force your attribute to repeat....you will get repeated values.